# Free airport transport between DXB terminal 2 and terminal 1

Tags: dubai, dxb

I'm in Dxb terminal 1. I want to go to Terminal 2. Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 have some Airport free transport available?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the red "Connections" signs to reach the airside shuttle bus that goes between T1, T2 and T3. You will need to go through a security check.

If you need help you can approach any staff member who is wearing the "May I help you?" shirt.